# How to upload a attached file using Jmeter for SOAP

Tags: soap, file-upload, wsdl, jmeter

I need to upload a file(xml) using jmeter. I know how to do it for REST calls. But this is for SOAP request. 
The request xml looks like,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://wsdl.api.doc.cdp.ipt.homeoffice.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:createDocument>
         <input>
            <instanceId>999</instanceId>
            <sessionId>999</sessionId>
            <content>file:aaa.xml</content>
            <mimetype>xml</mimetype>
         </input>
      </wsdl:createDocument>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Easy one**: just record your call using [JMeter's Proxy Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) or [Mobile Recorder service](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-) and replay it
2. **Harder one**: create POST request manually, switch [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to "Body Data" mode and construct it there like:

   [image: HTTP MTOM SOAP]

   See [Insert MTOM Attachment](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21455_01/common/tutorials/conversion_insert_mtom.html) for more details.
3. **Hardest one**: use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language to generate request on-the-fly (it'll be required if your SOAP server is a little bit paranoid and expect security header with timestamps, expiration date, usernames tokens, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

you can use web service soap request sampler to post it (check [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#WebService(SOAP)_Request_(DEPRECATED))) or you can try Http request sampler, please check [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) for handling it